# Grails javascript call controller method

Tags: javascript, grails

In a grails view I need to call a javascript method to get some info and so I have a submit action like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Generar" onclick="generateReport()" style="float: right" />
```

and at the end of the generateReport() I need to call/redirect to the `show` action of a Controller (because I'm at the `create` action already)

I'have tried with

```
1) var jSon = generateJSON();
    <g:remoteFunction controller="report" action="show" params="[data:jSon]" />

2) var jSon = generateJSON();
    <g:remoteFunction controller="report" action="show" params="[data:${jSon}]" />
```

1) data reaches null 
2) compile error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
Message
Attribute value quote wasn't closed (controller="report" action="show" params="[data:${jSon}]").
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `remoteFunction` or any of the `remote*` tags. They are old, difficult to work with, and no longer supported in newer versions of Grails. You need to learn to make your own ajax calls using jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this..

declare a variable in your gsp like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var yourVariable = "${createLink(url: [controller: 'yourController', action: 'yourAction'])}";
</script>
```

then in your js file..you can use ajax.

example ajax

```
function checkUsernameAvailable(user, example){
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: yourVariable, <- this variable take from your gsp
        contentType:"text/json",
        type: "get",
        data: ({ id: usernamenya}),
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
               //do something here
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
        }
    });                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**var json** cannot be assigned to data as params in , as var **jSon** is a javascript variable. Data in params attribute requires model parameter coming from controller.

In 1st option when it is assigned as params as it is not a model parameter from controller its showing **null**.

2nd option would not work as this is not the way to define model parameter from controller so giving **compile error**.

So you should better try getting jSon as model from controller and then define as params.

Or you can follow this link to define g:remoteFunction in onclick itself

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/remoteFunction.html

Hope this helps! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `remoteFunction` tag won't work for your situation because it's rendered into html and JavaScript (server side) *before* the value of jSon is known (client side).

You'll have to do the ajax call on your own (ex. Jquery).